# Plutus starter cabal build issue

Tags: plutus, cabal, docker, plutus-starter

Running the instructions at https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus-starter#readme

After opening the container in VSCode, and attempting to run the following in the terminal.

```
[devcontainer]$ cabal build
Killed
[devcontainer]$ cabal update
Killed
```

Container is hosted on an M1 Macbook Air with 4GB allocated to docker.

Admittedly, I am new to Haskell and Cardano, so it's not yet apparent to me if this may be a resources issue or something in the plutus starter project.

Comment: Have exact same issue on M1 Pro.

Answer (score 1):

I believe there are some compatibility problems with M1s and Docker. It might be worth trying to run Cabal through nix-shell instead.

Comment: Continuing to work through nix-shell on an M1 system, but I'll accept this answer if I get it going.

Answer (score 0):

Yesterday i found out that if you do a cabal build with limited amount of cpus `cabal build --jobs=1` you get quite far but after building for like 2 hours ... it gets killed after all ... seems to be a docker issue with ressource management i think!